# inequality by taking cases

Tags: probability-theory

The setup is the following: We have a sequence of r.v. $X_n$ and $X$. We define $Y_n:=\frac{1}{2}(X_n+X)$. Moreover $F$ is a strict convex Function such that $$ \lim\sup  P[F(Y_n)\le \frac{1}{2}(F(X_n)+F(X))-\delta]\ge \delta >0 $$

for some $\delta >0$. We have clearly $F(Y_n)\le \frac{1}{2}(F(X_n)+F(X))$. By taking cases I want to establish

$$E[F(Y_n)]-\frac{1}{2}(E[F(X_n)]+E[F(X)])\le 0-\delta P[F(Y_n)\le \frac{1}{2}(F(X_n)+F(X))-\delta]\le -\delta^2$$

I think we have to choose $A:=F(Y_n)\le \frac{1}{2}(F(X_n)+F(X))-\delta$ and $A^c=F(Y_n)> \frac{1}{2}(F(X_n)+F(X))-\delta$.

I started in the following way:

$$E[F(Y_n)]=E[F(Y_n)\mathbf1_A]+E[F(Y_n)\mathbf1_{A^c}]\le E[(\frac{1}{2}(F(X_n)+F(X))-\delta)\mathbf1_A]+E[F(Y_n)\mathbf1_{A^c}]$$

With the first term, I can use:

$$E[(\frac{1}{2}(F(X_n)+F(X))-\delta)\mathbf1_A]\le \frac{1}{2}(E[F(X_n)]+E[F(X)])-\delta^2$$

Since I can choose a subsequence (again denoted by $X_n,Y_n$) such that $P[F(Y_n)\le \frac{1}{2}(F(X_n)+F(X))-\delta]\ge \delta$ for all $n$. To conclude I must somehow show that $E[F(Y_n)\mathbf1_{A^c}]\le 0$. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you are after but the setting seems to be the following:

> Let $(Z_n)$ denote a sequence of almost surely nonnegative random variables such that, for some positive $\delta$, $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}P[Z_n\geqslant\delta]\geqslant\delta$. Then $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}E[Z_n]\geqslant\delta^2$.

In your setting, $Z_n=\frac12(F(X_n)+F(X))-F(Y_n)$.

The proof is direct. For every $k$, choose $n_k$ such that $P[Z_{n_k}\geqslant\delta]\geqslant\delta-1/k$ and deduce from the almost sure nonnegativity of $Z_{n_k}$ that $E[Z_{n_k}]\geqslant\delta P[Z_{n_k}\geqslant\delta]$, QED.

Note finally that to establish $E[Z_n]\geqslant\delta^2$ for a given $n$ is hopeless, starting from the *asymptotic* hypotheses made here.

Comment: Obviously this answer does not fit the title of the question. Somehow, I tend to blame the title, not the answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually my notes make the statement $E[Z_n]\ge \delta^2$, but what we really want at the end, is an asymptotic hypotheses, namely: $\lim\inf E[F(Y_n)]\le \frac{1}{2}(\lim\inf E[ F(X_n)+F(X))])-\delta^2$. Using your proved asymptotic estimate and $\lim\sup -x_n=-\lim\inf x_n$, I get: $\lim\inf E[F(Y_n)]\le \frac{1}{2}(\lim\sup E[F(X_n)]+E[F(X)])-\delta^2$. Can I just replace the $\lim\sup$ on the RHS with $\lim\inf$ ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, we know that $\lim E[F(X_n)]=L$, hence $\lim\sup E[F(X_n)]=\lim\inf E[F(X_n)]=L$ and everything is fine. Thank you so much! I'm happy with your solution, since the suggested "taking cases" seems wrong to me. I will reward the bounty in 23h

Comment: Quite generally, $\liminf E[F(Y_n)]\leqslant\limsup E[F(Y_n)]$. If $E[F(X_n)]\to L$ then $\limsup E[F(Y_n)]\leqslant\frac12(L+E[F(X)])-\delta^2$.